# Clicking layout opens new fragment with same images

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app in which first screen contains 4 different layouts with different images as background. What i want to do is if I click on one layout new fragment opens up with that background image on the top. Can i use same fragment to display different images and textviews ? if yes how ?

[not able to upload image due to less points ]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



    }

    // Click methods goes here

    public  void clickAboutUs(View v)
    {
        /*Intent aboutUs = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentAboutUs.class);
        startActivity(aboutUs);*/

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragmentAboutUs = new FragmentAboutUs();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,fragmentAboutUs);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }







    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


FragmentAboutUs.java


public class FragmentAboutUs extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_us, container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

on clicking an layout i want fresh fragment screen with same image as background image of that particular background image which is stored in my drawables folder.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKX4L.png
```

Comment: I hope you'll edit your `activity_main.xml` with code  `- -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use same fragment for displaying different images and texts. You can add image resource id or path and the texts you want to display in arguments. Just initialise your fragment from main activity as below;

```
    MyFragment myFragment = new myFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("image",<image resourse id>);
    bundle.putString("text1",<your string1>);
    bundle.putString("text2",<your string2>);
    myFragment.putArgs(bundle);
```

And inside your my fragment in ONcreate or ONcreateView get the data as below
         Bundle bundle = getArguments();
         imageId=bundle.getInt("image");
         text1=bundle.getString("text1");
         text2=bundle.getString("text2");

Hope this helps. Any doubt let me know.

Comment: just use my answer and customize it to match your fragment. It should work